# How to check whether shinken need reload?

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to use pynag with shinken and `pynag.Model.config.needs_reload` always return True for there is no `object_cache_file` in shinken, which is an old design in nagios and no longer needed in shinken.

I don't want to call `object_cache_file` back. Is there any native method for shinken to check whether `shinken-arbiter` needs reload?